Is it ok to support a 10.1lb ceiling exhaust fan using a 2x4 on top of drywall rather than the provided metal brackets?
I bought a 10.1 lbs bathroom exhaust fan replacement (Panasonic Whisper model FV-0511VFL1). While the electricians were cleaning up, they walked out with the EX install metal bracket included with the fan. I asked why they didn't use it. They replied that they screwed one side into the truss, and because the drywall was 1/2" they just put a 2x4 on attic-side of the ceiling and screwed the other side into the 2x4. I'm an amateur, they were apprentices but close to exams and becoming journeymen, so I said ok if that's how it goes.
Later I went into the attic to respread the insulation back to cover the truss bottoms. I saw the 2x4 and wondered if it was legitimate.



If the other side is indeed fastened to a ceiling joist I'd have no concerns. I can't see that in your photos, though. Why not?

I appreciate all the helpful edits, especially you isherwood, thank you. The joist/rafter is parallel on the other side of the opposite side of the 2x4. It wasn't the question so I didn't think about taking a picture. Not sure if 10 lbs is item or gross box weight. I wish those were differentiated better in online sales pages. The box was a pound tops, and the only other thing was the install bracket a few oz tops. So still probably 8 or 9 pounds. Thank you all

The metal bracket is to be used if fastening to a framing member (Joist or truss) is not possible.
The way your fan is mounted, ( assuming it indeed is attached to a truss) is preferred. You are fine.

Ok. I thought support from two solid timbers would be better than one side a free floating 2x4, but that's why we ask questions, to learn. These stackexhange websites are a jewel in the internets.

The only thing I would be worried about is it getting a vibration but other than that you should be ok.

True. I'll never mount a fan rigidly to framing again. The 60 Hz hum is really annoying.

Vibration would be a problem. The model has a DC motor to reduce sound (~1 sone out of 5 loudest), so if there's hum I haven't heard it like I have with all the past AC motors. Only problem with DC motor is it takes about 9 seconds to start (1st world problem)

Many vent fans are made to basically lay on top of the ceiling drywall, using bend-out tabs in the metal box to clamp the box to the drywall.  I wouldn't worry about the weight.
